# Cloning html and giving unique id with required attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, laravel-5

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".pd_add").click(function() {
    var newpd = $(".pdclone").html();
    $(".pdincrement").after(newpd);
    $(newpd).find('input[type=text]:nth-child(1)').attr("required", "required");
    $(newpd).find('input[type=file]:nth-child(1)').attr("required", "required");
    $(newpd).find('input[type=select]:nth-child(1)').attr("required", "required");
    $(newpd).find('input[type=select]:nth-child(1)').attr("id", Math.floor(Math.random() * 100));
    //    $(newpd).insertAfter(".pdclone:last");
  });
  $("body").on("click", ".pd_remove", function() {
    $(this).parents(".pdcontrol").remove();
  });
});
```

```css
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-me-12">
  <div class="input-group control-group pdincrement">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-4">
        <div class="form-group has-feedback">
          <label for="pdtype[]">Document Type<span class="text-danger">*</span>                                         
          <i class="fa fa-question-circle" data-toggle="tooltip"
                                                   data-placement="top" title=""
                                                   data-original-title="Please Select Document type"></i>
                                            </label>
          <br>
          <select name="pdtype[]" id="pd_1" required="true">
            <option value="citizenship">citizenship</option>
            <option value="license">license</option>
            <option value="passport">passport</option>
          </select>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="col-md-3">
        <div class="form-group has-feedback">
          <label for="pddocument[]">Document<span class="text-danger">*</span></label>
          <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-open-file form-control-feedback" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Select Document" data-original-title="Please Select Document"></i>
          <input type="file" required class="form-control" accept=".jpeg, .jpg, .png, .pdf, .doc, .docx" name="pddocument[]" placeholder="Browse Document">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-4">
        <div class="form-group has-feedback">
          <label for="pdremarks">Remarks<span class="text-danger">*</span></label>
          <input autofocus type="text" class="form-control" name="remarks[]" placeholder="Remarks" value="" required minlength="2" maxlength="255">
          <span class="fa fa-info form-control-feedback"></span>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-1"><label> </label><span><br></span>
        <button class="btn btn-success pd_add" id="pd_add" type="button"><i
                                                    class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></i>Add</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>


  <!-- This is hidden    -->
  <div class="pdclone hide ">
    <div class="row control-group input-group pdcontrol" style="margin-top:10px">
      <div class="col-md-4">
        <div class="form-group has-feedback">
          <label for="pdtype[]">Document Type<span class="text-danger">*</span>
                                                <i class="fa fa-question-circle" data-toggle="tooltip"
                                                   data-placement="top" title=""
                                                   data-original-title="Please Select Document type"></i>
                                            </label><br>
          <select name="pdtype[]" id="pd_1" required="true">
            <option value="citizenship">citizenship</option>
            <option value="license">license</option>
            <option value="passport">passport</option>
          </select>

        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-3">
        <div class="form-group has-feedback">
          <label for="pddocument[]">Document<span class="text-danger">*</span></label>
          <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-open-file form-control-feedback" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Select Document" data-original-title="Please Select Document"></i>
          <input type="file" required="false" class="form-control" accept=".jpeg, .jpg, .png, .pdf, .doc, .docx" name="pddocument[]" placeholder="Browse Document">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-4">
        <div class="form-group has-feedback">
          <label for="pdremarks[]">Remarks<span class="text-danger">*</span></label>
          <input autofocus type="text" id="pdremarks_1" class="form-control" name="pdremarks[]" placeholder="Remarks" value="" required="false" minlength="2" maxlength="255">
          <span class="fa fa-info form-control-feedback"></span>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-1">
        <label> </label><span><br></span>
        <button class="btn btn-danger pd_remove" type="button"><i
                                                    class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></i>Remove</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I know only the basics of javascript. I am making a form to get user input just like document type, remarks and document(file). I have used clone to get multiple documents at a time and its difficult to give validation to cloned elements. Without changing id select2 doesn't work so that I want to change the cloned element's id and required field from false to true. Is it possible? 
Here is my code:

```
  <div class="modal-body">
    <form novalidate id="entryForm" action="{{URL::Route('client.pd_store')}}" method="post"
          enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <div class="box-body">
            @csrf
            <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">
            <input type="hidden" name="id" value="{{$client->id}}">

            {{--repeating from here--}}
            <div class="input-group control-group pdincrement">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-4">
                        <div class="form-group has-feedback">
                            <label for="pdtype[]">Document Type<span class="text-danger">*</span>
                                <i class="fa fa-question-circle" data-toggle="tooltip"
                                   data-placement="top" title=""
                                   data-original-title="Please Select Document type"></i>
                            </label>
                            <br>
                            {!! Form::select('pdtype[]', $pd, '' , ['id'=>'two','class' => 'form-control select2', 'required' => 'true']) !!}
                            {!! Form::select('pdtype[]', $pd, '' , ['id'=>'five','class' => 'form-control select2', 'required' => 'true']) !!}
                            <span class="text-danger">{{ $errors->first('pdtype[]') }}</span>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-md-3">
                        <div class="form-group has-feedback">
                            <label for="pddocument[]">Document<span class="text-danger">*</span></label>
                            <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-open-file form-control-feedback"
                               data-toggle="tooltip"
                               data-placement="top" title="Select Document"
                               data-original-title="Please Select Document"></i>
                            <input type="file" required class="form-control"
                                   accept=".jpeg, .jpg, .png, .pdf, .doc, .docx" name="pddocument[]"
                                   placeholder="Browse Document">
                            <span class="text-danger">{{ $errors->first('pddocument[]') }}</span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-4">
                        <div class="form-group has-feedback">
                            <label for="pdremarks">Remarks<span class="text-danger">*</span></label>
                            <input autofocus type="text" class="form-control" name="remarks[]"
                                   placeholder="Remarks" value="{{old('pdremarks[]')}}" required
                                   minlength="2"
                                   maxlength="255">
                            <span class="fa fa-info form-control-feedback"></span>
                            <span class="text-danger">{{ $errors->first('pdremarks[]') }}</span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-1"><label> </label><span><br></span>
                        <button class="btn btn-success pd_add" id="pd_add" type="button"><i
                                    class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></i></button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>


            {{--hidden div  --}}
            <div class="pdclone hide ">
                <div class="row control-group input-group pdcontrol" style="margin-top:10px">
                    <div class="col-md-4">
                        <div class="form-group has-feedback">
                            <label for="pdtype[]">Document Type<span class="text-danger">*</span>
                                <i class="fa fa-question-circle" data-toggle="tooltip"
                                   data-placement="top" title=""
                                   data-original-title="Please Select Document type"></i>
                            </label><br>
                            {!! Form::select('pdtype[]', $pd, '' , ['required'=>'false','id'=>'pdtype_1','class' => 'form-control select2']) !!}
                            <span class="text-danger">{{ $errors->first('pdtype[]') }}</span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-3">
                        <div class="form-group has-feedback">
                            <label for="pddocument[]">Document<span class="text-danger">*</span></label>
                            <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-open-file form-control-feedback"
                               data-toggle="tooltip"
                               data-placement="top" title="Select Document"
                               data-original-title="Please Select Document"></i>
                            <input type="file" required="false" class="form-control"
                                   accept=".jpeg, .jpg, .png, .pdf, .doc, .docx" name="pddocument[]"
                                   placeholder="Browse Document">
                            <span class="text-danger">{{ $errors->first('pddocument[]') }}</span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-4">
                        <div class="form-group has-feedback">
                            <label for="pdremarks[]">Remarks<span class="text-danger">*</span></label>
                            <input autofocus type="text" id="pdremarks_1" class="form-control"
                                   name="pdremarks[]"
                                   placeholder="Remarks" value="{{old('pdremarks[]')}}" required="false"
                                   minlength="2"
                                   maxlength="255">
                            <span class="fa fa-info form-control-feedback"></span>
                            <span class="text-danger">{{ $errors->first('pdremarks[]') }}</span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-1">
                        <label> </label><span><br></span>
                        <button class="btn btn-danger pd_remove" type="button"><i
                                    class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></i></button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <!-- /.box-body -->
        <div class="box-footer">

            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-info pull-right upload-image"><i
                        class="fa fa-plus-circle "></i>
                Upload Document
            </button>
            <a href="#" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">Cancel</a>

        </div>
    </form>


</div>
```

//here is the javascript code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $(".pd_add").click(function () {

            var newpd = $(".pdclone").html();
            $(".pdincrement").after(newpd);
            $(newpd).find('input[type=text]:nth-child(1)').attr("required","required");
            $(newpd).find('input[type=file]:nth-child(1)').attr("required","required");
            $(newpd).find('input[type=select]:nth-child(1)').attr("required","required");
            $(newpd).find('input[type=select]:nth-child(1)').attr("id",Math.floor(Math.random() * 100));
            $(newpd).insertAfter(".pdclone:last");

        });

        $("body").on("click", ".pd_remove", function () {
            $(this).parents(".pdcontrol").remove();
        });
        Generic.initCommonPageJS();
    });
</script>
```

My interface looks like this
[image]

Comment: Please click [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/55278465/edit) then click `[<>]` snippet editor and paste RENDERED HTML and relevant css and script to make a [mcve] - we cannot eyeball compile our templates

Comment: Please have a look at snippet editor

Comment: `Without changing id select2 doesn't work` where's that part of the code?  You shouldn't need any ids.  If you mean the LaravelCollective `Form::` tags - I see you have added id attributes there, but where do you use them?  Try getting rid of them.

Comment: You posted TWO sets of code. Which one gives the problem?

Comment: I want to use select2 in the solution but it is not working in cloned select2.

Answer (score 0):

I changed many things in your code for it to work properly:

- Replaced [`:nth-child(1)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-child) by [`:eq(0)`](https://api.jquery.com/eq-selector/) for finding your text and file inputs.
- Replaced `input[type=select]:nth-child(1)` by [`select:first-of-type`](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/CSS/:first-of-type) for finding your select.
- Added a counter in order to know what will be the next ID. It increases each time a form block is appended.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  let count = 1;

  $(".pd_add").click(function() {
    let $newpd = $($(".pdclone").html());
    
    $(".pdincrement").after($newpd);
    
    $newpd.find('input[type=text]:eq(0)').prop("required", true);
    $newpd.find('input[type=file]:eq(0)').prop("required", true);
    $newpd.find('select:first-of-type').prop("required", true);
    $newpd.find('select:first-of-type').attr("id", `pd_${count + 1}`);
    
    count++;
  });
  
  $("body").on("click", ".pd_remove", function() {
    $(this).parents(".pdcontrol").remove();
  });
});
```

```css
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-me-12">
  <div class="input-group control-group pdincrement">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-4">
        <div class="form-group has-feedback">
          <label for="pdtype[]">Document Type<span class="text-danger">*</span>                                         
          <i class="fa fa-question-circle" data-toggle="tooltip"
                                                   data-placement="top" title=""
                                                   data-original-title="Please Select Document type"></i>
                                            </label>
          <br>
          <select name="pdtype[]" id="pd_1" required="true">
            <option value="citizenship">citizenship</option>
            <option value="license">license</option>
            <option value="passport">passport</option>
          </select>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="col-md-3">
        <div class="form-group has-feedback">
          <label for="pddocument[]">Document<span class="text-danger">*</span></label>
          <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-open-file form-control-feedback" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Select Document" data-original-title="Please Select Document"></i>
          <input type="file" required class="form-control" accept=".jpeg, .jpg, .png, .pdf, .doc, .docx" name="pddocument[]" placeholder="Browse Document">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-4">
        <div class="form-group has-feedback">
          <label for="pdremarks">Remarks<span class="text-danger">*</span></label>
          <input autofocus type="text" class="form-control" name="remarks[]" placeholder="Remarks" value="" required minlength="2" maxlength="255">
          <span class="fa fa-info form-control-feedback"></span>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-1"><label> </label><span><br></span>
        <button class="btn btn-success pd_add" id="pd_add" type="button"><i
                                                    class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></i>Add</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>


  <!-- This is hidden    -->
  <div class="pdclone hide ">
    <div class="row control-group input-group pdcontrol" style="margin-top:10px">
      <div class="col-md-4">
        <div class="form-group has-feedback">
          <label for="pdtype[]">Document Type<span class="text-danger">*</span>
                                                <i class="fa fa-question-circle" data-toggle="tooltip"
                                                   data-placement="top" title=""
                                                   data-original-title="Please Select Document type"></i>
                                            </label><br>
          <select name="pdtype[]" id="pd_1" required="true">
            <option value="citizenship">citizenship</option>
            <option value="license">license</option>
            <option value="passport">passport</option>
          </select>

        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-3">
        <div class="form-group has-feedback">
          <label for="pddocument[]">Document<span class="text-danger">*</span></label>
          <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-open-file form-control-feedback" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Select Document" data-original-title="Please Select Document"></i>
          <input type="file" required="false" class="form-control" accept=".jpeg, .jpg, .png, .pdf, .doc, .docx" name="pddocument[]" placeholder="Browse Document">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-4">
        <div class="form-group has-feedback">
          <label for="pdremarks[]">Remarks<span class="text-danger">*</span></label>
          <input autofocus type="text" id="pdremarks_1" class="form-control" name="pdremarks[]" placeholder="Remarks" value="" required="false" minlength="2" maxlength="255">
          <span class="fa fa-info form-control-feedback"></span>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-1">
        <label> </label><span><br></span>
        <button class="btn btn-danger pd_remove" type="button"><i
                                                    class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></i>Remove</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```